# Classes in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, class

I am currently learning TS and I wanted to see if I understand the following.  I know that a class in TS can include a property, a constructor, and a method.  We are creating a new object with new Greeter, and running the constructor to initialize it with "world".

```
class Greeter {  
greeting: string;  

constructor(message: string) {  
this.greeting = message;   
}  

greet() {  
return "Hello, " + this.greeting;   
  } 
} 
let greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the constructor assigns the value "world" to the 'greeting' property of the new object 'greeter'.

```
console.log(greeter.greet())
```

will console log as:

```
Hello, world
```